# PyTorch - Effect of normal() initialization on gradients

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

Suppose I have a neural network where I use a normal distribution initialization and I want to use the mean value which is used for initialization as a parameter of the network.

I have a small example:

```py
import torch
parameter_vector = torch.tensor(range(10), dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
sigma = torch.ones(parameter_vector.size(0), dtype=torch.float)*0.1
init_result = torch.normal(parameter_vector, sigma)
print('requires_grad:', init_result.requires_grad)
print('result:       ', init_result)
```

This results in:

```
requires_grad: True
result:        tensor([ 0.1026,  0.9183,  1.9586,  3.1778,  4.0538,  4.8056,  5.9561,
         6.9501,  7.7653,  8.9583])
```

So the `requires_grad` flag was obviously taken over from the mean value tensor resp. `parameter_vector`.

But does this automatically mean that the `parameter_vector` will be updated through `backward()` in a larger network where `init_result` does affect the end result?

Especially as `normal()` does not really seem like normal operation because it involves randomness.

Comment: you better use the reparametrization trick if you want to do that https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/342815/133099 that allows you to backprop through the sampling operation

Comment: @iacolippo Thank you, this is really good to know! I will try it that way, but do you know how it is implemented in pytorch? Haven't found yet the actual source code where the generation is done.

Comment: relevant issue (instructive read): https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4620 they advise to use `torch.distributions`

Comment: Thank you, I will go through the issue-thread. I implemented the way you suggested from cross-validated. It works so far, but there is a new flag displayed in the print out: `tensor([-0.0047,  0.8995,  1.9992,  2.9483,  3.9291,  4.8601,  5.9526,  6.9122, 8.0088,  8.8857], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)` - any idea what `grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>` means? Haven't seen this before.

Comment: Okay, it seems it just says it's result of adding tensors. So I guess it works now - thanks a lot!

Comment: `grad_fn` is the function that computes the gradient, in this case `<ThAddBackward>` is the name of the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@iacolippo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4892874/iacolippo) (see comments below the question) the problem is solved now. I just wanted to supplement this by posting what code I am using now, so this may help anyone else.

As presumed in the question and also stated by [@iacolippo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4892874/iacolippo) the code posted in the question is not backpropable:

```
import torch
parameter_vector = torch.tensor(range(5), dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
print('- initial parameter weights:', parameter_vector)
sigma = torch.ones(parameter_vector.size(0), dtype=torch.float)*0.1
init_result = torch.normal(parameter_vector, sigma)
print('- normal init result requires_grad:', init_result.requires_grad)
print('- normal init vector', init_result)
#print('result:       ', init_result)
sum_result = init_result.sum()
sum_result.backward()
print('- summed dummy-loss:', sum_result)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([parameter_vector], lr = 0.01, momentum=0.9)
optimizer.step()
print()
print('- parameter weights after update:', parameter_vector)
```

***Out:***

```
- initial parameter weights: tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.], requires_grad=True)
- normal init result requires_grad: True
- normal init vector tensor([-0.0909,  1.1136,  2.1143,  2.8838,  3.9340], grad_fn=<NormalBackward3>)
- summed dummy-loss: tensor(9.9548, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)

- parameter weights after update: tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.], requires_grad=True)
```

As you can see calling `backward()` does not raise an error (see linked issue in comments above), but the parameters won't get updated either with SGD-Step.

---

#### Working Example 1

One solution is to use the formula/trick given here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/342815/133099

> x=μ+σ sample(*N*(0,1))

To archive this:

```
sigma = torch.ones(parameter_vector.size(0), dtype=torch.float)*0.1
init_result = torch.normal(parameter_vector, sigma)
```

Changes to:

```
dim = parameter_vector.size(0)
sigma = 0.1
init_result = parameter_vector + sigma*torch.normal(torch.zeros(dim), torch.ones(dim))
```

After changing these lines the code gets backprobable and the parameter vector gets updated after calling `backward()` and SGD-Step.

**Output with changed lines:**

```
- initial parameter weights: tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.], requires_grad=True)
- normal init result requires_grad: True
- normal init vector tensor([-0.1802,  0.9261,  1.9482,  3.0817,  3.9773], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)
- summed dummy-loss: tensor(9.7532, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)

- parameter weights after update: tensor([-0.0100,  0.9900,  1.9900,  2.9900,  3.9900], requires_grad=True)
```

---

#### Working Example 2

Another way would be using `torch.distributions` [(Documentation Link)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html).

Do do so the respective lines in the code above have to be replaced by:

```
i = torch.ones(parameter_vector.size(0))
sigma = 0.1
m = torch.distributions.Normal(parameter_vector, sigma*i)
init_result = m.rsample()
```

**Output with changed lines:**

```
- initial parameter weights: tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.], requires_grad=True)
- normal init result requires_grad: True
- normal init vector tensor([-0.0767,  0.9971,  2.0448,  2.9408,  4.1321], grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)
- summed dummy-loss: tensor(10.0381, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)

- parameter weights after update: tensor([-0.0100,  0.9900,  1.9900,  2.9900,  3.9900], requires_grad=True)
```

As it can be seen in the output above - using `torch.distributions` yields also to backprobable code where the parameter vector gets updated after calling `backward()` and SGD-Step.

I hope this is helpful for someone.